# Implementing jQuery into Ember.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have asked to make tweeks to an app created in Ember.js, but I haven't had much experience with it. I have removed/addded fields, added the necessary text, and the one the last tasks to do is validate to fields (phone numbers) to make sure they are identical. It works on my localhost, but it doesn't on the Ember app.

Here is the Ember.js

```
data.buffer.push("\n      </div>\n    </div>\n\n    <div class=\"form-

row\">\n      <div class=\"field w100\">\n        <label for=\"primary_phone\">Primary phone (digits only) *</label>\n        ");
  hashContexts = {'type': depth0,'name': depth0,'required': depth0,'placeholder': depth0,'title': depth0};
  hashTypes = {'type': "STRING",'name': "STRING",'required': "STRING",'placeholder': "STRING",'title': "STRING"};
  options = {hash:{
    'type': ("number"),
    'name': ("primary_phone"),
    'required': ("required"),
    'placeholder': ("e.g. 12025556789 (country code + area code + local number without dashes)"),
    'title': ("e.g. 12025556789 (country code + area code + local number without dashes)")
  },contexts:[],types:[],hashContexts:hashContexts,hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data};
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(((stack1 = helpers.input || depth0.input),stack1 ? stack1.call(depth0, options) : helperMissing.call(depth0, "input", options))));

   data.buffer.push("\n      </div>\n    </div>\n\n    <div class=\"form-row\">\n      <div class=\"field w100\">\n        <label for=\"confirm_phone\">Confirm Primary phone (digits only) *</label>\n        ");
  hashContexts = {'type': depth0,'name': depth0,'required': depth0,'placeholder': depth0,'title': depth0};
  hashTypes = {'type': "STRING",'name': "STRING",'required': "STRING",'placeholder': "STRING",'title': "STRING"};
  options = {hash:{
    'type': ("number"),
    'name': ("confirm_phone"),
    'required': ("required"),
    'placeholder': ("e.g. 12025556789 (country code + area code + local number without dashes)"),
    'title': ("e.g. 12025556789 (country code + area code + local number without dashes)")
  },contexts:[],types:[],hashContexts:hashContexts,hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data};
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(((stack1 = helpers.input || depth0.input),stack1 ? stack1.call(depth0, options) : helperMissing.call(depth0, "input", options))));
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(function(){
var $primaryNo = $("input[name='primary_phone']");
var $confirmNo = $("input[name='confirm_phone']");
var $btn = $('#button');

$primaryNo.keypress(function(key) {
    if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) 
    return false;
});

$confirmNo.keypress(function(key) {
    if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) 
    return false;
});

$btn.click(function() {
     if ($primaryNo.val() !== $confirmNo.val()) {
        alert('The numbers from the Primary Phone field and the Confirm Primary Phone field do not match. Please re-enter');
     } else {
        return true;
     }

});

});
```

I have conducted some tests with console.log and the Ember app is picking up the .js file I have included, but when I click submit when two different numbers are inserted into the fields, it doesn't alert the user they are incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you have posted does not look like Ember.js code.

Comment: The previous developer said he used Ember.js. What would you say it is written in?

Comment: The HTML5 produced displays:
<input id="ember817" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" name="last_name" required="required">

Comment: Perhaps a very old version or build artifact? Have a look in [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/) and [Ember Cli User Guide](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/) to get a feeling how an ember app should look like these days. Perhaps there is a package.json or bower.json giving you an idea of dependencies?

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you

Comment: jquery comes preloaded in ember under `Ember.$` are you sure this is ember code? Does the ember app show up under the [ember inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector)?

Comment: @Kitler Thank you for pointing me to that tool. Yes it is, Ember 1.4.0 and handlebars 1.3.0

Comment: 1.4 was a long long long time ago x.x I m not sure anyone can help with this.

Comment: Haha.... I am doomed. Thank you for help anyways

Answer (score 0):

try event delegation:

```
$(function(){
var $primaryNo = $("input[name='primary_phone']");
var $confirmNo = $("input[name='confirm_phone']");
var $btn = $('#button');

$('body').on('keypress',$primaryNo,function(key) {
    if(key.keyCode < 48 || key.keyCode > 57) 
    return false;
});

$('body').on('keypress',$confirmNo,function(key) {
    if(key.keyCode < 48 || key.keyCode > 57) 
    return false;
});

$('body').on('click',$btn,function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($primaryNo.val() !== $confirmNo.val()) {
        alert('The numbers from the Primary Phone field and the Confirm Primary Phone field do not match. Please re-enter');
     } else {
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
     }

});

});
```

Comment: Thanks but still no luck, and also I have other fields that require text input

Comment: what errors do you have in the console? is your code even triggering?

Comment: If it's an Ember.js app you should not use jQuery, at least not this way. For validation you would use a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/) for validation state / error message. There are [several validation addons available](https://emberobserver.com/categories/validations). So lets clear this before.

Comment: It's not coming up with any errors. It is reading the file and logging any commands I give it, but it doesn't seem to be validating the two fields

Comment: are your keypress event firing?

Comment: No. I think the problem is (sorry if I don't explain this well), in my template.js file where you create the templates of the page, the jQuery works elements that have been stated in the file, but can't read the elements such as the input fields generated by Ember.js